# How to remove a Honeywell Braukmann 104v radiator actuator

Tags: radiator, hydronic

I have a radiator with a Honeywell 104V radiator actuator that I'd like to replace, I think it's P/N T104V1422. I can't seem to figure out how the thing is connected to remove it. The rest of the house uses 104A actuators which have a locking ring that just unscrews when it's properly aligned, but the 104V doesn't seem to be setup that way. I've searched for videos and documentation but haven't found anything regarding removing it. I've tried unscrewing it but it only seems to turn left or right a few degrees before stopping. I'm hesitant to try and brute force it off lest I do more harm than good.I've posted a picture of the valve in question.

[image: My Valve]